# What weapons do Predators use?

Tags: alien-vs.-predator, predator, predator-series

When I played *Aliens versus Predator* video game as a Predator, I really enjoyed his set of weapons. I remember the spear, disk, a cannon and a tool for self-healing.

In the *Aliens versus Predator* movie, the Predator also uses a web that tightens itself killing a person inside of it.

What other weapons are the Predators equipped with?

Comment: Self-destruction device. Shuriken. Blue all-solve-around fluid. Wrist blade.

Comment: There are extensive weaponry guides here; http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Weapons_and_technology_of_the_Hunt and here; http://aliens.wikia.com/wiki/Yautja_Weapons as ten seconds of googling would have shown you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it implies a list answer. It might be argued that the list is finite, but with all the various video games and comic books, it would be far from a short or static list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [AVP wiki](https://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Yautja_%28Predator%29#Clothing_and_armor), Predators (Yautja) have the following:

> **Equipment**
>
> - *Cloaking Device*: Light-bending adaptive camouflage allowing Predators a form of invisibility, or at least translucence. The invisibility effect has been known to be shorted out through contact with water, or if the arm gauntlet is damaged.
> - *Bio-Mask*: The Predator's mask contains systems to enhance its vision and provide additional vision modes in other electromagnetic spectra. It also grants access to Vocal Mimicry and the Language Translator, and records anything the Predator sees so that it may be reviewed at a later date.
> - *Wrist Gauntlet*: Includes the Predator's Sat-Com and sometimes a Plasma Bolt or Power Punch Glove. Also incorporates touch-pad technology to control a Predator's Cloaking Device, Self-Destruct Device, and even remotely pilot Predator vessels.
> - *Medi-Kit*: Predator hunters carry field medical equipment including solvents capable of cauterizing and healing Predator wounds and various serums and other medical devices.
>
> **Weapons**
>
> - *Wrist Blades*: Razor-sharp serrated blades worn on a wrist gauntlet for close combat.
> - *Scimitar*: Essentially an enlarged Wrist Blade worn on the forearm.
> - *Plasma Caster*: A ranged weapon capable of directing plasma bolts at distant targets. Aimed through the Predator's Bio-Mask.
> - *Plasma Cannon*: A hand-held version of the Plasma Caster.
> - *Spear Gun*: A projectile weapon that fires small metal spears, comparable to a traditional firearm or crossbow.
> - *Combi-Stick*: A retractable spear that can be used either in hand-to-hand combat or as a thrown weapon.
> - *Net Launcher*: A handheld device capable of firing a wire net with enough force to pin a target to a wall. The net also features an automatic tightening mechanism designed to cause grievous wounds to the enclosed target.
> - *Smart-Disc*: A self-guiding discus-like cutting device.
> - *Shuriken*: Similar to the Smart-Disc, except considerably larger and fitted with several fan-like blades.
> - *Glaive*: Similar to the Combi-Stick, this combat staff is fitted with a sizeable blade at each end.
> - *Maul*: A heavy bladed weapon comparable to a police officer's nightstick.
> - *Whip*: A segmented bull whip capable of slicing targets in half with enough force.
> - *Mines*: Predators utilize a variety of mines with varying trigger mechanisms and detonation effects in their hunts.